OneDrive overwriting local changes on Word document
I was working on my Microsoft Word 365 document for 8 hours yesterday offline, with no internet access, saved on to my local drive (in my Onedrive folder). When I opened the file with internet connection today, it said there were conflicts to resolve, and I resolved the conflicts to my satisfaction. I then closed the file, made a copy, moved the file to a new onedrive folder, and then opened the file, and all the conflicts and resolved conflicts have gone, and there is just the version from 3 days ago. Do you know how to recover an offline copy of the file that was there yesterday?
Things to note:
I regularly saved the local copy, and had local autosave on.
I have tried using:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/recover-an-earlier-version-of-an-office-file-169cb166-e7e2-438e-8f39-9a8927828121?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us
I have looked in C:\Users\ <user>\AppData\Local\ and various folders in here.
Does anyone have any advice as to how to get back my original copy?

You should in any case be able to go to the webversion of OneDrive and open earlier versions of a document there

It was never on the web version. The versions are Friday and today (Monday), so sadly this doesn't work.

I think it went wrong because you moved the file. Maybe the file is in the recycle bin on the old location.
